# connector lines between two ellipse

Tags: silverlight

I am developing an application in silverlight in which i am creating a Ellipse dynamically on button click, which is draggable across the form.
Now i want to have a connector line between two ellipse like dragging at center point from one ellipse and leaving at the other should create me the connector line.
And this connector line should be updated when i move the ellipse controls in movemove.

Help... Help...

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this?

Answer (score 0):

this code example might help you:

http://kindohm.com/archive/2008/08/25/connectable-lines-and-shapes-in-silverlight.aspx